# how to write formula for max marks as per attached image

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how to write formula for max marks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:$D$2,A3:D3,"<>AB")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following formula spills the entire result:

```
=MMULT(IF(A3:D4<>"AB",A2:D2,0),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:D2),,1,0))
```

or using `BYROW` (shorter but probably less efficient than `MMULT` for a very large dataset) as follows:

```
=BYROW(IF(A3:D4<>"AB",A2:D2,0), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Another alternative using `ISNUMBER` which also leaves out blanks (I can see that this may come handy if you fill out the data when not all is completed yet) `=BYROW(ISNUMBER(A3:D4)*A2:D2, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))`